# how to make spark "read excel" parser get value from the formula bar instead of the values displayed in the cell?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I need to read the entire original pre​ci​sion of the cell, example: I need 23.1234567892 instead of 23.123 which is the display value of the cell.(obtained after clicking on decrease decimal button in excel).

| name | score |
| --- | --- |
| james | 23.123 |
| jim | 24.9876 |

Actual value in the formula bar : 23.1234567892

[Check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHnWX.png)

Below is my current spark read options , could I add any existing options to achieve above requirement?

```
val originalDf = spark.read
  .format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
  .option("sheetNamePattern", section.section_name)
  .option("cellAddress",section.header_start_pos)
  .option("headerRowCount", 1)
  .option("enforceSchema",false)
  .option("orientation","ROW")
  .option("usePlainNumberFormat",true)
  .option("verbose",true)
  .schema(schema)
  .excel(listOfFilesToProcess: _*)
```

I tried the option("usePlainNumberFormat",true) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What is the dtype of that column? Did you try "decimal(m,n)" dtype in your schema?

Comment: @ErenSakarya thanks , enforcing schema to doubletype captures the entire gamut of precision

Comment: No problem, please add it as an answer for others who also struggle with it.

Answer (score 1):

Casting decimal column as DoubleType helped capture the entire gamut of decimal in the formula bar of the excel , rather than what is displayed in the cell .

```
val customSchema = StructType(Array(
  StructField("dates", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("name", StringType, nullable = true),
  StructField("numbers", DoubleType, nullable = true),
  StructField("desc", StringType, nullable = true)
))



val originalDf = spark.read
      .format("excel")
      .option("sheetNamePattern", section.section_name)
      .option("cellAddress",section.header_start_pos)
      .option("headerRowCount", 1)
      .option("enforceSchema",true)
      .option("orientation","ROW")
      .schema(schema)
      .excel(listOfFilesToProcess: _*)
```